# "A 1000-sqft room" vs. "a 1000 sq. ft. room"

Tags: adjectives, abbreviations, hyphenation, measuring-units

Which of the following is correct?

> This is a 1000-sqft room
>   This is a 1000 sq. ft. room

Or perhaps neither is right and there's a better alternative?

Comment: Different acronyms are used: http://www.allacronyms.com/square_feet/abbreviated, http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_foot

Comment: In BrE, 'square foot' is often abbreviation to sf, so I might see 'This is a 1,000sf room'.

Comment: Which are you trying to differentiate on, "sqft" vs "sq. ft.", or the hyphen after 1000?

Comment: Please never just ask “Which is correct?”  It shows no effort on your part, and gives us nothing to go on.  As [the Help Center says in its “How to ask a good question” section](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask):  **“Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!”** Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The [U.S. Government Printing Office Style Manual (PDF)](http://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/GPO-STYLEMANUAL-2008/pdf/GPO-STYLEMANUAL-2008.pdf),
in multiple contexts throughout Section 12 (“Numerals”),
gives the following examples of correct usage:

- the 1-mile road
- 6-inch guns
- four-room houses
- 5-foot-wide entrance
- seven-story building
- 8-year-old wine

So, while I can’t find a rule that actually spells this out,
they seem to favor a hyphen between the number and the unit of measurement.

In Section 9, “Abbreviations and Letter Symbols”,
they say that “square foot” is abbreviated “ft<sup>2</sup>”,
but they don’t show any examples of using it with a number. 
They support the abbreviation “sq.” only when referring to place names; e.g., Herald Sq.

Answer (score 1):

According to [NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sqft%2Csq.+ft.%2Csq+ft%2Csquare+foot%2Csquare+feet%2Csquare-foot%2Csquare-feet&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csqft%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csq.%20ft.%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csq%20ft%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csquare%20foot%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csquare%20feet%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csquare%20-%20foot%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csquare%20-%20feet%3B%2Cc0), "sq. ft." or "sq ft" is vastly preferred over "sqft".

The use of a hyphen is a stylistic choice but due to the nature of "sq. ft." being two words the options are rather limited:

> 1000 sq. ft.
>
> 1000 square-foot

The specific example of "1000-sqft" is non-standard.

Answer (score 0):

"This is a 1000 square-foot room." The Associated Press style guide has a section on dimensions. Although it doesn't directly say, the examples online show no hyphen between the number (or units) and what is being measured. You should spell out the units entirely.

There is no central authority on how to write proper English, so there may be other acceptable answers also.

Citing the Purdue Associated Press style page because the official AP reference is behind a paywall:
https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/735/02/

Edit - Found an official answer on an AP FAQ. Search "dimensions" to find it:
https://www.apstylebook.com/?do=ask_editor&pg=faq

Comment: But the [AP FAQ](https://www.apstylebook.com/?do=ask_editor&pg=faq) gives the example "3-year-old house".

Comment: That follows the same convention.  There is no hyphen between the units and the object being measured. It isn't "3-year-old-house".

Comment: OK, I may have _slightly_ misread your proclamation – because it was irrelevant to the question. The OP didn’t suggest “1000-sqft-room” or “1000 sq. ft.-room”, so why did you even state the undocumented rule about no hyphen between the measure and the noun? My point is, the OP gave two options, one of which had a hyphen ***immediately after the numeral*** and one of which didn’t.

Comment: Your answer was to present an alternative with _no_ hyphen after the number – and then cite a rule (for which you could provide no source), having to with hyphens but not bearing on the question. And then you point to a reference that gives examples _with_ a hyphen between the number and the units, including “68,000-square-foot facility”, which I overlooked last week, which is directly relevant to the question (and which conflicts with your answer).